# Combine data of single row from Multiple tables of a Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, multiple-tables

Here's the situation:

I have a Dataset with multiple tables (7 to be exact). All I want is to combine each row from every table to form a string.

Example: If dataset fetches two records, then the first row from every table is combined first to form a string. If any row of any particular table doesn't generate a result it would generate empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Having a DataSet called `ds`

You could do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            sb.Append(table.Rows[i][table.Columns[j]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this would give me the entire contents of one table in single string.
I want first row from every table in first string.

Comment: @prashant you did not make that clear on your question. And you only care about the first row? You need to put more effort into explaining what you need

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop and fetch data.